# Does the equation converges uniformly on R?

Tags: complex-analysis

Does the function converges uniformly on $\Bbb R$? 
 $$\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac {e^{i \operatorname{Im} \sin(z)}}{ n^5}$$

Comment: Did you mean "...on $\;\Bbb C\;$" ?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\left|\frac{e^{i\,\text{Im}(\sin z)}}{n^5}\right|\le\frac1{n^5}\;\;+\;\;\text{Weierstrass M-Test}$$

Comment: When I work it out it, the series converges, so am i right to say that it also converges uniformly in R?

Comment: Is the above inequality true for **all** $\;z\in\Bbb C\;$? Then the answer is yes...and why you keep on talking about the reals if the given series is complex